# AngularJS $http, error handling, interceptors and response status code 0

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I expected that bad requests would fall in the function defined inside $http#error, but that does not happen. Instead I had to create an interceptor. And even though I know the status code should be 404, the returned status code in the response is 0.

```
 $http({url: "myurl", method: "GET"}).success(
   function(data, status, headers, config) {
     if (data.ret_code === 200) {
        //do something
     }
   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     //NEVER GETS HERE ON BAD REQUEST!!
   });
```

and here is the interceptor:

```
var interceptor = ['$q', function ($q) {

  function success(response) {
    return response;
  }

  function error(response) {
    //ALWAYS 0!
    var status = response.status;

    return $q.reject(response);
  }

  return function (promise) {
    return promise.then(success, error);
  }
}];
```

1-Why is this?
2-Is there a way to catch bad requests in $http#error?
3-Is there a way to get the actual 404 status code?

Comment: Is it hitting your server?

Answer (score 1):

I know of a "bug" in Android where files delivered from the browser cache give a statuscode 0.

Github Issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1720

Hacked-up Fix (from the same page):

```
// fix status code for file protocol (it's always 0) and 0 status code for http(s) protocol on Android devices
status = (protocol == 'file') ? (response ? 200 : 404) : (response && status == 0 && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') !== -1 ? 200 : status);
```

Comment: Here is why -1 as status

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#146-multiplicative-elevation-2015-09-17

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $rootScope to interceptor and update your error function something like this

```
function error(response) {
    if (response.status === 0) {
       $rootScope.errorStatus = 'No connection. Verify application is running.';
    } else if (response.status == 401) {
       $rootScope.errorStatus = 'Unauthorized';
    } else if (response.status == 405) {
       $rootScope.errorStatus = 'HTTP verb not supported [405]';
    } else if (response.status == 500) {
       $rootScope.errorStatus = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else {
      $rootScope.errorStatus = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    }
   return $q.reject(response);}
```

You can use errorStatus object to display your error details.